# Is there a more commonly-used term for "multi-pivoting"?

Tags: terminology, partitions

Consider the following computational problem (or rather, task):

> **Given:**
>
> - An array of $A$ of (not necessarily distinct) elements from a fully-ordered finite domain
> - An ordered sequence pivot values $p_1 \ldots p_m$ (i.e. such that $i < j \implies p_i < p_j$).
>
> **Output:**
>
> A partition of $A$ into $m+1$ parts (be they sets or shorter arrays),
>   denoted $A'_0 \ldots A'_m$ , such that if $i < j$ and $x \in A'_i$
>   then $x < p_j$.

One could call this computing a "histogram with variable-size bins", or "m-pivoting", or "m-way ordered partitioning", etc.

But are there names for this task which are more commonly used than others?

<sub>PS - If it helps, we can relax the requirement on the pivots to $p_i \leq p_j$.</sub>